# A mod migrated my old question to another SE site where I have already asked a new better question - how to merge these?

Tags: support, comments, moderator-tools, migration, merged-questions

I have asked [this question](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/120797/why-did-a-tradition-to-add-a-must-use-default-array-to-functions-was-created-and) on Retrocomputing; it got answers there, but was later closed and commenters suggested it would be a better fit for Computer Science.

Because my Retrocomputing question already got answers, I couldn't delete it before reposting it on Computer Science.

So, I went to Computer Science and posted a similar question there which is per my humble opinion [shorter, more focused, and better phrased](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/120796/why-in-general-must-function-declarations-be-followed-by-a-parameter-set).

But, after doing so, my old question from Retrocomputing was reopened and migrated to Computer Science, so two questions that are the same exist there.

[Now, in CS SE, there is a "salad" of two similar questions](https://cs.stackexchange.com/users/115711/johndoea?tab=questions) which per my humble opinion, needs to be merged somehow --- comments and answers from the old should be migrated to the new, I think.

### My question

A mod migrated my old question to another SE site where I have already asked a new better question - how to merge these?

I already contacted the mods of Computer Science explaining the problem and asking to merge the questions, but the flag was declined.

Please help in explaining what I should further do in this case.

Comment: @Alex I'm not sure, because I already contacted the mods there to merge and the questions weren't merged --- my flag was declined.

Comment: There was probably not enough information in your flag to explain the exact problem. I'd make a post on the per-site meta explaining what exactly happened.

Comment: hello @SonictheAnonymousHedgehog ; kindly I tell you, I humbly believe this is not correct. I think I well detailed the problem in the flag. I ask the community's intervention in solving this problem, where I don't have the technical ability to do so directly.

Comment: Still, though, I'd recommend a per-site meta post on Computer Science. There, you have more space to explain the issue and can get either another shot at merging them, or a more thorough explanation of why merging them is inappropriate (if it is).

Comment: @SonictheAnonymousHedgehog - done. Thanks,